# Spell Checker using word

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am writing a code in c# for spell checker. I found this code on the net. I am new to c# and am not able to understand the code.

I found this code on the following website:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4572/Using-Word-s-spellchecker-in-C

May i just get to know a general guideline on what is actually happening n the code:

```
using Word;

using System.Reflection;


private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 

{ 

    fSpellCheck(textBox1 , label1 ); 

}



public void fSpellCheck(TextBox tBox, Label lLbl) 

{ 

    int iErrorCount = 0; 

    Word.Application app = new Word.Application(); 

    if (tBox.Text.Length > 0) 

    { 

        app.Visible=false; 

        // Setting these variables is comparable

        // to passing null to the function. 

        // This is necessary because the C# null

        // cannot be passed by reference. 

        object template=Missing.Value; 

        object newTemplate=Missing.Value; 

        object documentType=Missing.Value; 

        object visible=true; 

        object optional = Missing.Value; 

        _Document doc = app.Documents.Add(ref template, 

           ref newTemplate, ref documentType, ref visible); 

        doc.Words.First.InsertBefore (tBox.Text ); 

        Word.ProofreadingErrors we = doc.SpellingErrors; 

        iErrorCount = we.Count; 

        doc.CheckSpelling( ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, 

            ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, 

            ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, 

            ref optional, ref optional); 

        if (iErrorCount == 0) 

            lLbl.Text = "Spelling OK. No errors corrected "; 

        else if (iErrorCount == 1) 

            lLbl.Text = "Spelling OK. 1 error corrected "; 

        else 

            lLbl.Text = "Spelling OK. " + iErrorCount + 

                                    " errors corrected "; 

        object first=0; 

        object last=doc.Characters.Count -1; 

        tBox.Text = doc.Range(ref first, ref last).Text; 

    } 

    else 

        lLbl.Text = "Textbox is empty"; 
    object saveChanges = false; 

    object originalFormat = Missing.Value; 

    object routeDocument = Missing.Value; 

    app.Quit(ref saveChanges, ref originalFormat, ref routeDocument); 

}
```

Comment: Did we answer your question? Please respond.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically what the code above does.

1) It opens a new Word instance in hidden mode
2) It inserts the text from your textbox into the first section of the document 
3) It invokes the spellchecker on the word document 
4) It Gets the error count from the spellchecker and prints the number of errors to your label 
5) It asks Word to correct the errors in the document. 
6) It copies the corrected text from the word document back to your textbox 
7) It closes the document and quits the hidden Word instance.

**What you need to do in your project:**
1. Create a label (if you dont have one already)
2. create a textbox (if you dont have one already)
3. Create a button(if you dont have one already)

Add a click event to your button, and in that code, call *fSpellCheck* like its done in this code, with your label and your textbox as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't much experience on C#, but I suppose you have an application with a GUI, with a button, a label and a textbox.

The method `button1_Click` is needed to assign an action to the button, when is clicked, a sort of an event listener for the button.
When you click on this button, `button1_Click` is executed, and the method `fSpellCheck(textBox1 , label1 );` is invoked.

The method `fSpellCheck(textBox1 , label1 );` implements the algorithm for checking the word, inserted by a textbox (note the textbox reference in the arguments of `fSpellCheck`). The method check the word for errors, if the word is correct or wrong(with errors) or if the textbox is empty, then the method prints in a label `lLbl` the result of the word control.